# Differential calculus on locally convex spaces

Tags: calculus, locally-convex-spaces

For real finite dimensional vector spaces $V,W,Z$, i know that a map $f:V \times W \to Z$ is  smooth if the maps $f(v,.)$ and $f(.,w)$ are for every $v\in V, w \in W$. Does the same thing hold for (possibly infinite dim.) locally convex spaces?

Comment: When the spaces $V,W$ are infinite dimensional and $Z$ is the real set there are several types of smoothness such as Gateaux, Frechet, etc. If $Z$  is infinite dimensional it is hard to define smoothness. So what do you mean by smooth?